# How to create a launcher in XFce4 that does not open items twice?

Tags: xfce, launcher

I have a custom launcher that opens a command such as:

leafpad ~/file1.txt

That opens a specific file that I must work on quite often.

Is it possible to adjust the command so that it is aware if the file has already been open in Leafpad, so by pressing it a second time, it just switches to that file and application, instead of opening a new instance?

Comment: this may help ... https://superuser.com/questions/1439340/determine-what-file-a-local-leafpad-instance-has-open

Comment: @Village Did you have any issue with my answer below working on your system? I tested with leafpad on Debian 9 and had no issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install `wmctrl` to achieve this with the following command:

`bash -c 'wmctrl -a file1.txt || leafpad ~/file1.txt'`

The `-a` option switches to the window with the title containing `file1.txt`. However if the command fails, i.e. `||`, then it will open your file.